# Comparing two excel sheet columns in asp.net web application in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, highlight

I want to make a asp.net web application in c#.net in which i can upload two excel sheets and after that asp.net web application should highlight the unmatched rows. Sorry, if I am asking too much, but Iam new and don't know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can stat with ADO.Net where you can easily read the excel file.
And after reading the excel file you can put them in data table or some collection an you can compare them.

Few helpful links
[Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)
http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196

Few link to compare DataTables
[Compare two DataTables and select the rows that are not present in second table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713243/compare-two-datatables-and-select-the-rows-that-are-not-present-in-second-table)

http://canlu.blogspot.in/2009/05/how-to-compare-two-datatables-in-adonet.html