# Comparing 2 DataTables in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have one `DataSet` object which contains two `DataTable` objects. Both `DataTable` have the same structure but first of them is older then second. Second `DataTable` contains part of the older `DataTable` object rows and some new rows. I need to know which rows has been added to "newer" `DataTable` comparing to the older.

I thought about method which takes two parameters (older and newer `DataTable`) and returns `DataRow[]` collection containing added rows to newer `DataTable` :

```
private DataRow[] GetNewDataRows(DataTable oldDT, DataTable newDT)
    {
        // code
    }
```

I don't know how to achieve that. Can anyone help ? 
Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713243/compare-two-datatables-and-select-the-rows-that-are-not-present-in-second-table

Comment: Take the max id or creationdate from old table. Then select all rows in the new tables with an id > that id.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for some thing like check col value

```
var dtData1 = datatable1.AsEnumerable().Select(a => new { ColValue = a["SomeCol"].ToString() });
var dtData2 = datatable2.AsEnumerable().Select(a => new { ColValue = a["SomeCol"].ToString() });

var exceptXY = dtData1.Except(dtData2);

DataTable dtMisMatch = (from a in datatable1.AsEnumerable() 
                       join xy in exceptXY on a["SomeCol"].ToString() equals ab.ColValue select a).CopyToDataTable();
```

I may not understood correctly but thought this help you.